# media query not working in bootstrap mobile mode

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries

I have a media query in my bootstrap [website](https://news.justinechacko.in/) like

```
@media (max-width: 688px) {
    .carousel-item>img {
        max-height: 175px !important;
    }
}
```

It worked before. But now it seems to be not working. Do you get any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an anchor tag between class and `img` tag. So I need to use as follows,

```
@media (max-width: 688px) {
    .carousel-item > a img {
        max-height: 175px !important;
    }
}
```

Notice the change from `img` to `a img`.